# Search Parameter

Tags: c#, design-patterns, design-principles

I have a screen which does a basic search on a database employee table.

User will search by First Name, Last Name, Department, IsActive, etc.

As of now I have created a SearchParameter Class :

```
public class EmployeeSearchParameter
{
    public EmployeeSearchParameterType SearchParameterType { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeSearchParameterValue { get; set; }
}


public enum EmployeeSearchParameterType 
{
    FirstName = 1,
    LastName = 2,
    EmpId= 3,       
    IsActive = 4
}
```

Will this be flexible in case if I have more options that support Custom paging like start row number, end row number, sort by, etc?

Or I can create an **abstract class** Search and implement?

```
 public abstract class Search
 {
  public virtual Int PageSize=10;
  public virtual string SortBy="DESC"
  //..etc
  }

 public class EmployeeSearchParameter:Search
 {//stuffs
 }
```

or ISearch **interface**

```
  public class EmployeeSearchParameter:ISearch    
  { }
```

Any input for better design/simplicity and not over-architecting the problem?

Comment: Parameters like page-size and sort order ideally are decided by the user and hence would be concerns of UI. The Search should only provide a way to perform the search and not really be concerned by the page size value

Comment: If you are looking for flexibility in building your select querry, take a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13419/SelectQueryBuilder-Building-complex-and-flexible-S

Answer (score 2):

Your `*Search*` class is actually what the [DAO Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_object) should be used for. If you call it differently your project will not be easily understood by other developers. In concrete, you will define an interface `IEmployeeDao` and corresponding implementation `EmployeeDao`. The public interface will include CRUD and finder methods e.g. `create`, `update`, `delete`, `findByName`, etc. For sample code in C# You should Google for DAO and Value List handler implementations for C#. I am only aware of sample code for the Java platform.

The second use-case you mention of navigating the results produced by the DAO implementation is another separate pattern, the [Value List Handler pattern](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/Patterns2ndEd/ValueListHandler.htm) that builds on top of your DAO implementation and provides functionality for navigating the results in different ways.

Comment: Ok. What should i follow? Do i need any code changes or please share your code if you have any, that helps me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The downside of using the DAO pattern is similar to the downside of the repository pattern: You hide away the searching capabilities of the underlying technology in favour of writing a very limited set of possible queries.

If your DAO / repo begins to expose ever more and ever more flexible search capabilities, it's very likely that the implementation will approach a similar layout to how your [DAL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_access_layer) works anyways; it is likely that you will start to develop a Query type to express more complex relations. And this already exists in various DB access technologies. (And is, i believe, a more c# idiomatic way to phrase search queries, compared to the DAO.)

There are [examples on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15189149/how-to-use-mongodbs-query-and-querybuilder-in-c-sharp-foreach-loop) and elsewhere for how query types might look; if you can expose your data through `IEnumerable` (or probably better `IQueryable`), accessing it through [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LINQ) would be very flexible and powerful.